# how to get a field from a model in django api view

Tags: python, django

i have to api views that use a model. i tried use headlines.objects.all() to get everything in the model and the second view is supposed to get only the title field from the model, i have tried filtering and i got a positional argument error. this is my views file.

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from news.models import Headline
from news.api.serializers import *

@api_view(['GET',])
def api_detail(request, any):
    try:
        qs = Headline.objects.get(slug=any)
    except Headline.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    if request.method == "GET":
        serializer = HeadlineSerializer(qs)
        return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET',])
def api_head(request):
    try:
        py = Headline.objects.all().filter(title=title).order_by('-id')
    except Headline.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    if request.method == "GET":
        serializer = HeadlineSerializer(py, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This is my serializers.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from news.models import Headline

class HeadlineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Headline
        fields = ['title', 'contentt']
```

here is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from news.api.views import *

app_name = 'news'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:any>/', api_detail, name='details'),
    path('', api_head, name='api_head'),


]
```

Comment: how you pass the title in api_head view ? show your urls

Comment: i didn't pass it. i have added my urls.py

Comment: ok , so how you can  filter by title if title is not define ?

Comment: i did it before, it didn't work. i removed everything except the filter(mistake).

Comment: ok, and some things: in api_head yo do try/expect with except Headline.DoesNotExist, is useless, no exeption when you filter , only when you get/first/last ..ect, and "if request.method == "GET":" same , rest framework with api_view decorators do this for you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at this line:

```
py = Headline.objects.all().filter(title=title).order_by('-id')
```

`title` is not a variable defined here.

If i understood you right you want to get just the field title, so you would get a response like:

```
[
     {
         "title": "lorem"
     },
     {
         "title": "ipsum"
     },
]
```

To achieve this you could create another serializer for that view.

```
class HeadlineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Headline
        fields = ['title', 'contentt']  


class HeadlineTitleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Headline
            #fields will filter you response for which fields you want to return in the response.
            fields = ['title']
```

In you view:

```
@api_view(['GET',])
def api_detail(request, any):
    try:
        qs = Headline.objects.get(slug=any)
    except Headline.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    if request.method == "GET":
        serializer = HeadlineSerializer(qs)
        return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET',])
def api_head(request):
    py = Headline.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    if request.method == "GET":
        serializer = HeadlineTitleSerializer(py, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I know. I need two separate views. One for title and one for title and content. If I change this, it would mean I cannot use the first one that has title and content.

Comment: You can have 2 serializers, one for title and one for title+content.

Comment: I've updated the response. This should work, otherwise I'm not sure I understand your question completely.